Creating a partition on linux
I have a Lenovo Ideapad 3, it runs on Lux.
However, i want to setup dual-boot with windows.
I cannot unmount the disc, even when running gparted Live from an usb stick (see image)

https://i.sstatic.net/QeJlMXnZ.jpg

Even if you create a partition for Windows, that OS does not like to share hardware. It will insist on removing any other OS installed on the machine. If you must have a bare metal installation of Windows, ensure your backups are up to date, install Windows, resize the partitions afterwards, then re-install Ubuntu. If a bare-metal installation of Windows is not required, then perhaps a VM will do what you need.

This question is similar to: Dual boot - what happens with "Install alongside windows" ??. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

What Ubuntu product/release you're using on your live session isn't stated, which doesn't allow us to be specific. It's also helpful if you provide the full messages you get, when using a GUI you may need to explore system logs for actual messages too (GUI apps tend to hide many messages as end-users can find them scary).  You've not provided any image that you reference.

@matigo I already use a VM, however my uni classes are using all the adobe programs now. If i were to use something like Premiere, running it on a VM, wouldnt there be a significant performance hit? Thats why i wanted to install windows.

@guiverc i previously ran gparted from a live usb running the latest ubuntu. That did not work so i opted to run gparted live from their website (latest version). The outcome ended up being the same. Also added the image back (typo on the link).

The color scheme on the picture does not match a Ubuntu system run live, and the zoomed in picture is hiding necessary detail; eg. if your partition table is legacy you cannot create any more partitions as table is full; but that detail doesn't show in your zoomed in picture. Linux support is at SE Unix & Linux, this is a Ubuntu support site.
